# Numbering fields in a growing square for easy calculation based on coordinates

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a square that slowly grows into a bigger square by adding more and more copies of the original square as shown in this picture below:

[image]

It starts with one square $(0)$, and then grows by 3 squares $(1, 2, 3)$ into a square that is twice as wide and twice as tall as the original. Then it grows again, this time by 5 squares $(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)$ to three times the original width and height. And so on...

I need to find a pattern that I can use to number these individual squares in such a way that I can later calculate the number in a square easily from its coordinates.

To give a couple of examples, let's use the numbering scheme above and look at the biggest square:

- $(0, 0)$: $0$
- $(1, 1)$: $2$
- $(3, 5)$: $28$
- $(4, 1)$: $23$
- $(x, y)$: $f(x, y)$

So, basically I need to come up with some $f(x, y)$ that fulfills the following requirements:

- It is independent of the size of the final square, i.e. I can use the same $f(x, y)$ for a $3\times 3$ square and a $200\times 200$ square (e.g. $f(x, y) = x + y*n$ is out as it depends on $n$)
- $0\le f(x,y)<n^2$, where $n=max(x, y)+1$
- $x$ and $y$ are integers $\ge0$ and $f(x, y)$ also returns an integer

All that these conditions basically say is that I need to number the squares in sequence as shown in the example above: The first time, I must add $(0)$, then I add $(1, 2,$ and $3)$, then $(4, 5, 6, 7,$ and $8)$. The only thing I am allowed to do is change the order within one add-step. So, I could add $(3, 1, 2)$ instead in the second step, and I could add $(7, 4, 8, 5, 6)$ after that.

Or another way to put it: The numbers in a square don't change if that square becomes a sub-square of a bigger square and for any size square, there are no missing numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the numbering scheme you have already,
$$f(x,y)=m^2+m+x-y\ ,$$
where $m=\max(x,y)$.

Comment: Cool! So this works already. :) Do you know if there is a way to re-order the numbers to avoid the maximum-operation? (I'm designing a data-structure and max/min-operations are much slower than addition, subtraction, multiplication and division)

Comment: Nothing comes to mind.  But how is absolute value for speed?  You could use$$\max(x,y)=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$$if that helps.

Comment: An absolute value is still slow (both involve comparisons, max() compares the numbers and abs() compares one number against 0)... But it turns out there are some tricks involving binary operations that one can use to calculate the maximum without comparisons (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-the-minimum-or-maximum-max-of-two-integers-without-branching/)... I'll try that and see how it performs. And based on Sfarla's answer, I don't think I'll be able to get rid of the max() anyways...

Answer (score 1):

If we say that the $0$-th square is $0$. then the $n$-th square is obtained by $(n-1)$-th by adding a row and a column with the numbers from $n^2$ to $(n+1)^2-1$. So, the first thing to understand could be the first square in which a couple $(x,y)$ appears. This is obviously given by 
$$\max\{ x,y\}.$$
Say $k = \max\{ x,y\}$. Now you know that $f(x,y) \in \{ k^2, \ldots, (k+1)^2-1\}$.
Observe that the first of these numbers is assumed by $f$ when $x=0$, the second when $x=1$, an so on, till $x=k , y=k$ in which $f(k,k)=(\max\{x,y\})^2+k$. Now decreasing $y$ $f$ increases. So you can deduce that the function that you are looking for is given by
$$ F(x,y)= (\max\{x,y\})^2+x+\max\{x,y\}-y.$$